# Why does this query exclude records if the field order is changed

Tags: soql

I have code that works on a scratch org but isn't working in production. I've tracked it down to a query that's searching a table. The Apex code looks like this:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Tag__c
WHERE Name IN :LoanController.fieldTagMap.values()
ORDER BY Name
```

Here's `LoanController.fieldTagMap`:

```
private static Map<String, String> fieldTagMap = new Map<String, String>{
    'AppraisalExpiration__c' => 'Aprsl Expire Soon',
    'RateExpiration__c' => 'Lock Expire Soon'
};
```

I log into production and go to the dev console and execute this query:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Tag__c
WHERE Name IN ('Aprsl Expire Soon', 'Lock Expire Soon')
ORDER BY Name
```

Only the record with the name `"Lock Expire Soon"` is returned. So I try this query:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Tag__c
```

I get all the records including `"Aprsl Expire Soon"`. I copy the version in my query and paste it into the field and save the record, no change.

Two more clues:

- If I exclude the `ORDER BY`, I get both records back, but in the wrong order.
- If I retain the `ORDER BY` clause but reverse the order of fields of the `IN` clause, (`('Lock Expire Soon', 'Aprsl Expire Soon')`), I get both records back.

So by altering the query slightly, I can get both records back, but why should this matter? How can the order of my list of fields affect the returned records?

Comment: Definitely sounds like you found a bug.

Comment: How many records do you have on the Tag__c object in Prod Vs Scratch org?

Comment: @Swetha, our data creator class automatically creates 9 records in the scratch org when we use a script to create it. The production org has 13 records.

Comment: This seems like an org specific issue as I've not been able to replicate this in my org. Can you open a Support case and share the case number here so I can check further?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce these results in Dev Console (Execute Anonymous)

```
private static Map<String, String> fieldTagMap = new Map<String, String>{
    'AppraisalExpiration__c' => 'Aprsl Expire Soon',
    'RateExpiration__c' => 'Lock Expire Soon'
};
    
Tag__c tag1 = new Tag__c();
tag1.Name = 'Aprsl Expire Soon';
insert tag1;

Tag__c tag2 = new Tag__c();
tag2.Name = 'Lock Expire Soon';
insert tag2;

List<Tag__c> idList = [SELECT Id, Name
FROM Tag__c
WHERE Name IN :fieldTagMap.values()
ORDER BY Name];

System.debug(idList);
```

Results:

```
20:18:45:073 USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|(Tag__c:{Id=a1S5900000015XeEAI, Name=Aprsl Expire Soon}, Tag__c:{Id=a1S5900000015XfEAI, Name=Lock Expire Soon})
```

Are you sure there isn't a typographic error in one of your Name strings?

Comment: I am as positive as I can be. I've copied and pasted multiple times. For example, I launched `node` and executed `'Aprsl Expire Soon' === 'Aprsl Expire Soon'` where one of those was pasted from my query and the other from the record. _And_, when I reverse the order of the map's entries, it works.